# My ubuntu 16.04LTS logs into a blank screen

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

System: Intel HD Graphics 4000 adapter and NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M adapter visible in Windows; default drivers now in Ubuntu; latest GRUB installed.

I just installed ubuntu 16.04LTS on my computer to dual boot with windows 10. The computer worked fine for a while but now, after I log into ubuntu, after the desktop wallpaper and cursor are displayed, my screen literally sinks and goes black. Even my cursor disappears (no blinking cursor).

After doing a bit of looking up, I found out that this might be some graphics driver related issue. But when I select 'advanced options in ubuntu' from the GRUB screen, and boot into ubuntu recovery mode, I'm able to log in and access all my files normally. Then it can't be a driver issue, right? And trying the nomodeset thing from GRUB also didn't work for me.

I can't think of any new update that I did which could've suddenly caused this problem on a computer that was running so perfectly well. I'm sorry if I'm missing any important details in here... I'm new to ubuntu so please help out?! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have any GPU in use? Can you please describe your system fully in the beginning of the body. It sounds to me either GPU driver problem or GRUB problem.

Comment: I just booted into Windows and found that Intel HD Graphics 4000 is the adapter in use and there's built in NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M adapter too. On ubuntu there seems to be a lot of driver options... I'm going with the default driver at the moment... could that be the issue? And I have the latest GRUB update installed.

Comment: I added the info from your comment to your body. How did you install the latest GRUB? Can you give more information about your PC: brand, year-of-bought, processor, ... Can you say if your Bios is graphical or textual?

Comment: I ran this in windows as administrator : bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi Later I updated GRUB from ubuntu terminal while changing default OS from ubuntu to windows 10 on the GRUB console. Its a Samsung laptop - i5 processor, bought 2 years ago. I installed ubuntu alongside windows 10 two months back and this problem started two weeks ago. I'm not sure how to find out if my bios is textual or graphical...

Comment: Can you please describe how the problem started? Did you change anything? On Windows side or Linux side?

Comment: Thats the problem. From what I remember, I didnt change anything... Changing default OS to windows on GRUB menu was done by opening ubuntu in recovery mode... Problem had started earlier.